# PHP mPDF in Yi2 Image error! Нужна помощь

Tags: php, html, yii2, pdf, mpdf

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть код в HTML, внутри которого есть (png). Мне нужно формировать PDF документ. Использую Kartik mpdf (обертка над mpdf). Так вот когда ожидаю открытия документа в новой вкладке, то выдает ошибку: **"Call to undefined function Mpdf\Image\random_int()"**. Пробовал в src вставлять и ссылку, и через data:...base64;, и через file:///.. не работает. Как-то же он конвертирует изображения. Вопрос как. Может у кого была подобная ошибка. Буду признателен за помощь. 
Код формирования ниже:

```
$pdf = Yii::$app->Pdf; // это обертка над mpdf

$pdf->content = $html;
$pdf->cssInline = $style;

return $pdf->render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

правильный путь - установить библиотеку и ее зависимости с помощью Composer.

random_compat требуется: `https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat`

Также, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с кодом, чтобы узнать что-то о CSPRNG за random_int и его безопасных резервных копиях.

Comment: спасибо) помогло. Подскажите, это какая-то надстройка над php? Я не эксперт, не совсем понял почему ругался на random_int если в php есть эта функция. Скорее всего я что-то недопонял..